# Spring boot using @ComponentScan causes conflict between CrudRepository and Slack @Configuration and @Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, slack-api

I used the example code from Slack API to construct an app. It has the following configuration:

SlackApp.java

```
@Configuration
public class SlackApp {

    @Bean
    public AppConfig loadSingleWorkspaceAppConfig() {
        return AppConfig.builder()
                .singleTeamBotToken(System.getenv("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))
                .signingSecret(System.getenv("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET"))
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public App initSlackApp(AppConfig config) {
        App app = new App(config);
        if (config.getClientId() != null) {
            app.asOAuthApp(true);
        }
        app.command("/hello", (req, ctx) -> {
            return ctx.ack(r -> r.text("Hi!"));
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

Inside the database package:

1.StaffRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface StaffRepository extends CrudRepository<Staff, Integer>{

}
```

2. StaffController.java

```
@RestController
public class StaffController {
    @Autowired
    private StaffService staffService;

    @RequestMapping("/staffs")
    public List<Staff> getAllStaffs(){
        return staffService.getAllStaffs();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/staffs/{id}")
    public Optional<Staff> getStaff(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return staffService.getStaff(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/staffs")
    public void createStaff(@RequestBody Staff staff){
        staffService.createStaff(staff);
    }
}
```

3. StaffService.java

```
@Service
public class StaffService {
    @Autowired
    private StaffRepository staffRepository;

    public List<Staff> getAllStaffs(){
        List<Staff> staffs = new ArrayList<>();
        staffRepository.findAll().forEach(staffs::add);
        return staffs;
    }
    public Optional<Staff> getStaff(Integer id){
        return staffRepository.findById(id);
    }
    public void createStaff(Staff staff){
        staffRepository.save(staff);
    }
    public void updateStaff(Integer id, Staff staff){
        staffRepository.save(staff);
    }
    public void deleteStaff(Integer id){
        staffRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

4. Staff.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="staff")
public class Staff {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String date;
    String time;
    String name;
    String InOrOut;
    String whatFor;
    String summary;
    String company;
    Integer hours;

    public Staff(){}

    public Staff(Integer id, String date, String time, String name, String InOrOut, String whatFor, String summary, String company, int hours){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
        this.InOrOut = InOrOut;
        this.whatFor = whatFor;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.company = company;
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String timeStamp) {
        this.time = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getInOrOut() {
        return InOrOut;
    }
    public void setInOrOut(String inOrOut) {
        InOrOut = inOrOut;
    }

    public String getWhatFor() {
        return whatFor;
    }
    public void setWhatFor(String whatFor) {
        this.whatFor = whatFor;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public int getHours() {return hours;}
    public void setHours(int hours) {this.hours = hours;}

}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@EntityScan("example.database")
@ComponentScan({"example.database"})

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext myapp = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SlackApp.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my file structrue:

```
main
 +- java
     +- example
         +- Application.java
         +- SlackApp.java
         +- ......
         |
         +- database
         |   +- Staff.java
         |   +- StaffController.java
         |   +- StaffRepository.java
         |   +- StaffService.java
```

Here comes the problem:

If I add @ComponentScan({"example.database"}), it will show this error:

```
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in example.SlackAppController required a bean of type 'com.slack.api.bolt.App' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.slack.api.bolt.App' in your configuration.
```

If I remove @ComponentScan({"example.database"}), it will show this:

```
Description:
Field staffRepository in example.database.StaffService required a bean of type 'example.database.StaffRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'example.database.StaffRepository' in your configuration.
```

I also tried to move SlackApp.java into the database package, but it didn't work. Can someone help me, please?